# Auto-populating columns based on value in a column

Tags: sharepoint

I am creating a SharePoint Document Library.

When a document is uploaded the Content Type allows some columns to be added.

These columns are:

- `Code`, and
- `Retention period`, and
- `Retention Expiry Date`

There are a range of vales for `Code`, each with a unique retention period.

When a user selects a value for `Code` I would like to automatically populate `Retention Period` and `Retention Expiry Date` with the relevant values for this value of `Code`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

There are several options to achieve this.

The most obvious approach is to make the `Retention period` and `Retention Expiry Date` calculated columns. Then provide an [formula](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx) to populate those fields. The formulas used to do this in SharePoint are (largely) the same formulas used in MS Excel so you can practice writing them in Excel to ensure they work before implementing them in SharePoint.

It is impossible to give you examples of how to do this since you have not shared enough information to allow us to help you in detail.